# How can we bind the GridView control in asp.net using AngularJS?

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, gridview

I am a newbie to AngularJS.I want to bind the data to `GridView` control using AngularJS.I have done this task using HTML table it is working fine. Can we apply AngularJS databind for ASP.NET controls?

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a client-side tool.  `GridView` and other ASP.NET controls are rendered server-side.  So, there is no way for Angular to know about ASP.NET.  And if it does, that is probably a bad thing.

So, in your case, the HTML table is the correct approach.

Typically, Angular is a Single Page Application (SPA) and speaks to the server through AJAX calls to get data (usually JSON).  This development style makes server-side UI rendering obsolete.  Because you are just returning data, not rendered HTML.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you.I have one more question like Is service or WebAPI or REST are used to get the data from DB? So no event wire-up to the controls.

Comment: @HemantKumar Typically, yes.  A RESTful API is called through `$http` and there is no wire-up of server-side events.  They are completely separate applications.